# MQTT.js how to hook connected status with vuex

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, mqtt, vue-router

Am still learning vuex, i have a 3 export method connect to mqtt broker with call backs to console out.
The thing after page refresh the client disconnect and `client.on("end/disconnect")` is not fired.
was thinking if there was a way from software design perspective of view, on how to implement it with vuex to track client connection status and act accordingly.

EDIT:
here is my current code.

```
export let client = null

export var status = 'initial'

export var startSub = ({username, password}) => {
    client = mqtt.connect("ws://192.168.1.30:9001/mqtt",{
        clientId: `mqttjs_ + ${Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8)}`,
        username: username,
        password: password
    })
    client.on("connect", () => {
        status =  client.connected
        client.subscribe('hello/#')
        console.log("startSub，Subsecribed")
    }).on('error', err => {
        status =  client.connected
        console.log("error", err)
        client.end()
    }).on("message", (topic, message) => {
        status =  client.connected
        console.log(`topic, ${topic}, msg:: ${JSON.parse(message)}`);
    })

    //on disconnect call bacl
    client.on("disconnect", (packet)=>{
        status =  client.connected
        console.log('client of discconect call back', packet)
    })

    //on disconnect call bacl
    client.on("end", function () {
        console.log('client of end call back')
    })
}
```

now when the page refresh the client automatically disconnect.
on my vuex store, if i import status, as state, its useless to track because after refresh its always initial. to be more clear my aim is to after refresh to keep the connection active without it being disconnected.

Comment: Please add the actual code to the question, as it is it really isn't clear what you are asking. Also which MQTT Javascript library are you using? MQTT.js or Paho?

Comment: @hardillb yes MQTT.js latest version.
The thing is i have no idea how to do it, my question is for a direction, or whither or not its feasible.

Comment: @hardillb updated. thats all i got, i thought its useless any way, and wanted better idea/direction. any idea?

Comment: Neither `end` or `disconnect` will get called on a page reload as the client will just get discarded (so no `end`) and the remote broker will not send a disconnect packet (so no `disconnect`). I don't think there is any way to maintain a client connection across a page reload.

Comment: @hardillb do you suggest preventing page reload? if i wanted to keep the client connected and properly track `disconnect / end ` satatus?